# Cannot knit .rmd file into PDF, HTML or Word

Tags: r, r-markdown

My OS is MacOS Catalina. 
RStudio Version- 1.2.5

The trouble is with knitting R Markdown document to PDF, HTML or Word. Whenever I press "knit" I get the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  object 'vI' not found
Calls: :: ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

I have downloaded latest version of MacTex as well but still it doesn't seem to solve the problem. 
I've also installed important packages- rmarkdown, rcpp, knitr among others.

Please help! I'll be grateful if you can

Comment: It looks as if an object called `v1` is not being generated  when you knit. Have you checked `v1`?

Comment: It looks like some package is not up to date.  You could try `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` and update them all.

Comment: I agree with @Peter Either there is a called object missing in your code (meaning it is not there at all) or you have generated this object previously under another object name, renamed it, and forgot the adapt subsequent code correspondingly. This bug bit me already several times. You might want to check your ```RMarkdown``` code chunks manually by highlighting the code and pushing Ctrl + Enter to run the code. This should give you an information where the line containing the error can be found. However, this might not be working properly when you are using functions.

Comment: @Peter I couldn't find any specific solution regarding object "v1". The solutions I found involve reinstalling entire R and RStudio and all its packages (https://community.rstudio.com/t/knitr-setup-object-vi-not-found/53324). I think I will go ahead with that

Comment: @GRowInG I ran individual chunks and they ran just fine without any issues. There was no error at all. I can't figure out the problem with knitting

Comment: I found a related problem. When I load rmarkdown package using library(rmarkdown), I get a similar error:

**Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rmarkdown’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 object 'vI' not found**



Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: I'm running R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11),  with  rmarkdown_1.12 attached in RStudio $version  ‘1.2.1335’ And not getting any errors when I run the built-in rmarkdown .Rmd file. Could it be a version issue?

Comment: @Zirconix Yep, I would also try a new reinstallation and a restart of the computer after having read your link and another one https://community.rstudio.com/t/object-vi-not-found/38243 pointing into the same direction.

Comment: The `vI` object is in the base `loadNamespace()` function.  The only way I can see it might be missing is if you are trying to load a package that was installed for a different R version.  Try `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` if nothing else has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several methods but it didn't seem to solve any problem. So i went ahead and reinstalled R and RStudio. Everything has been running fine now. @user2554330 I think reinstallation fixed all the issues

Answer (score 0):

That error happens if a package is not properly installed.  From your description, it looks as though `rmarkdown` is probably the problematic package.  Re-install it and the error should go away.

The details are:  the `Meta/package.rds` file probably doesn't exist.  You can see if it exists using

```
list.files(file.path(system.file(package="rmarkdown"), "Meta"))
```

which should show

```
[1] "features.rds" "hsearch.rds"  "links.rds"    "nsInfo.rds"   "package.rds" 
[6] "Rd.rds"       "vignette.rds"
```

Comment: I removed the package and reinstalled it. 

I ran the code you mentioned **list.files(file.path(system.file(package="rmarkdown"), "Meta"))**

The results were as you mentioned in your comment. I still get the same error on loading the package. 

**Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rmarkdown’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 object 'vI' not found**

Comment: Something is definitely weird.  If you were on Windows, I'd suspect an antivirus; maybe they're just as bad on MacOS now.  Some other possibilities:  1. you have two copies of `rmarkdown` installed. `loadNamespace()` is trying the bad one, and when you install, you replace the good one.  2.  You aren't using `install.packages()` for your install, you're using some bogus one, e.g. from `devtools`.  3.  Somehow you have a bad copy of `loadNamespace()`.  Maybe RStudio installs its own?  If it were my system, I'd run `debug(loadNamespace)` to watch the failure happening.